# Not able to connect to mysql running in docker from another docker container

Tags: mysql, docker

I have a docker container running a mysql image,docker run command -

```
docker run --name=mysql -d -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root mysql/mysql-server:5.7
```

I am able to connect to this database from my SpringBoot app on localhost:3306, but when I run my springboot app -docker run command-

```
docker run --name=myservice -d -p 3306:3306 -p 8888:8888 <image-id>
```

it fails to start up and upon checking the logs I see, the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'liquibase' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration
$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is 
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: 
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

How do I make my spring boot app connect to the container running the mysql?

EDIT: adding the data-source part of my application.yml file for my app :

```
spring:
datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/<db-name>
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: root
jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
        ddl-auto: none
h2:
    console:
        enabledt: true
```

Comment: Connect those containers to common [`network`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/) or use `docker-compose`.

Comment: can you share `application.yml` file of spring boot ?

Comment: Also note that there is no need to _publish_ the port of the mysql container; doing so will make the mysql ports publicly accessible. If both containers are connected to the same network, your "myservice" container can connect to the "mysql" container, using `mysql` as hostname, and on it's default (3306) port.

Comment: oh; also, it looks like you're publishing port `3306` of the `myservice` container, which is likely not needed, and currently conflicts with port `3306` published by the `mysql` container, so one of both will fail (conflicting port / port already in use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by using --link mysql in the docker run command and changing datasource url from 'localhost:3306' to 'mysql:3306' in my application.yml , as by default Docker has a DNS and it can call containers by name.So, once linked and adding grant permission for my user 'root' for all IPs in my DB by bashing into 'mysql' container, I was able to start my service with the DB in another container. However, for a more general solution , creating a network or using docker compose seems like a better idea